# C# - datagridview doesn't show query result

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I need help with a code that's puzzling me: I'm a C # beginner and I'm pounding on some points and need help. In the project I have a simple form and a data source of a linked table in SQL Server. In this form I have a grid and three text boxes: the grid and 2 text boxes are with binding to the same data source; the other text box is to type the search

My goal is for the user to type the search in the text box and to make a filter in bindingsource through LINQ. Follow the code:

```
private void Search()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(toolStripTextBox1.Text))
    {
        var query = from v in coletasDataSet.UF
            select v;
        this.ufBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        string pesquisa = toolStripTextBox1.Text.ToLower().Trim();
        var query = from v in coletasDataSet.UF
            where v.UF.ToLower().Contains(pesquisa) 
            select v;
        this.ufBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();  
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I search the grid it just does not show any data. It holds the 2 columns (UF and ID_UF) and one blank line. I have debugged and checked the query result and it is coming correctly.

Any suggestion of what might be the problem? Detail: I can not pass the query.ToList () to the grid because it would have the text boxs with the bind showing one set of data and the grid showing another.

Comment: you can try calling `resetBinding` method to refresh the grid : `ufBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);`

Answer (score 1):

Use [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx)

> Binding list provides a generic collection that supports data binding.

Try Following

```
     var lstResult = from v in coletasDataSet.UF
                 where v.UF.ToLower().Contains(pesquisa) 
                 select new UF()
                 {
                    Id = u.pk,
                    Username = u.Username
                    ..........                    
               }).ToList();

     var resultSet = new BindingList<UF>(lstResult); // <-- BindingList

     //Bind BindingList directly to the DataGrid, no need of BindingSource
     myGrid.DataSource = resultSet;
```

Comment: I changed my code:

                var query = (from v in coletasDataSet.UF
                             where v.UF.ToLower().Contains(pesquisa)
                             select new UF()
                             {
                                 ID_UF = v.ID_UF,
                                 UF = v.UF
                             }).ToList();

                var result = new BindingList<UF>(query);

                this.ufBindingSource.DataSource = result;  

Now, I got error on UF. Any sugestion?

Comment: "The type or namespace 'UF' could not be found."

Comment: Uf was just an example in y answer , this will be your model(DTO)